# node js fluent-ffmpeg creating thumbnail

Tags: node.js, fluent-ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

currently im working on some video uploads, so i wanted to create a thumbnail during upload of videos.. I installated fluent-ffmpeg package but on first run i got error **Error: cannnot find ffprobe** then i changed **ffmpeg** to **ffmpeg.ffprobe** then i got undefined .on..
Heres my full code for video-upload:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const uuid = require('uuid/v1');
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');


const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
  'video/MPEG-4': 'MPEG-4',
  'video/mpeg-4': 'mpeg-4',
  'video/mp4': 'mp4',
  'video/MP4': 'MP4'
};

const videoUpload = multer({
  limits: 10000000,
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, 'uploads/videos');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
      const currentfilename = uuid() + '.' + ext;
      cb(null, currentfilename);

      
      ffmpeg.ffprobe(`uploads/videos/${currentfilename}`)
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log('Screenshots taken');
      })
      .on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      })
      .screenshots({
        count: 1,
        folder: 'uploads/videos/thumb',
        filename: uuid() + '_screenshot.' + ext
      });
    }
  }),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    let error = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid mime type!');
    cb(error, isValid);
  }

});

module.exports = videoUpload;
```

Comment: verify just the file upload part - no ffmpeg - to be sure where in the code the asnych #1  ( upld ) completes.  that is where your callback w ffmpeg piece should go - just follow the fluent docs as u have normal use case for the ffmpeg part.   make sure ffmpeg is NOT being called PRIOR to the 'onComplete' event on the upload part.

Comment: can u provide me some example on this code i post?

Answer (score 1):

See the thing is that `fluent-ffmpeg` provides you with functions to work with `ffprobe and ffmpeg` it does not provide you with them(so you have to install them manually in short). Other way would be to install 2 more libararies `@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg` and `@ffprobe-installer/ffprobe` and pass thr path into `fluent.ffmpeg`.[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971077/how-can-i-upload-a-video-to-s3-at-the-same-time-create-a-thumbnail-for-the-same/66398241#66398241)

Comment: i did install everything and used your code but now im getting: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: uploads/videos/cd302570-7ebf-11eb-98c1-a19b59997719.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input @ this is my currently code : https://pastebin.com/nxyvFf3X

Comment: Are you sure that the video you are trying to upload has 10 seconds, since you are taking a screenshot at 10th second. Also there seems to be issue with `[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000001345c0] moov atom not found` this not ffmpeg problem i guess.... got that from your stack trance.

Comment: Thanks, idk how i fixed i didnt change nothing but my code working now without errors :)

Comment: It seems like it was a problem with online convertor i used :)

Comment: If the code worked kindly mark the answer as right. Thanks